# What makes Windows Phone 8 Internet Explorer truncate html?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm making a webapp which recently broke on Windows phone 8.
https://marvin-brouwer.github.io/QR-Reader/

I've also tried the app on an Ipod Touch 3rd generation, an iPhone 4s and a Samsum Galaxy. The app works as expected on those devices.

To find out why it doesn't show what I expect I attached to my Nokia Lumia with Visual Studio which revealed the html being cut off.

I tried deminifying my html but it just gets cut off at a different part.

Is there any reason why this might happen? And is there a way to fix this? Or might this be a Windows Phone bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a html comment before the doctype which causes IE to go into quirks mode.

Also you have a xml comment which should be removed, this is html not xml.

More info: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/xml-declaration-in-html-xhtml/87783/2

Comment: If I read the HTML5 Specification it says I'm allowed to do that:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#writing, see point 2.  
Also I doubt having an xml declaration could be causing any of this, it's allowed in HTML5. I do believe it can create server errors in certain browsers so I will remove it but I don't think it could have caused the truncation.

Comment: Run it trough the w3c validator...It will say the same things I said. Also you're allowed to add comments above your doctype but IE will mess things up because it's IE...

Comment: Also it's the <!-- Copyright 2015, Multiple autors --> comment causing the issue in IE.

Comment: So the comment was the culprit indeed, but this still doesn't explain why this suddenly broke. I've had it like this for about a month now.

Comment: @MarvinBrouwer maybe you've had a meta tag in the past that forced the latest rendering mode in IE.

Comment: No, I didn't. The only thing I changed was some basic HTML beyond the point of truncation.